# How to set up a condition in a html type form?

Tags: html, web

How I set up a condition that requires a date as dd/mm/yyyy and for a gender (male/female or other)? 
I made this input type for the style with the other input types, but I want to set a condition to validate this fields.

```
<div class="input-container input9">
    <input type="#{type}" id="#{label}" required="required"/>
    <label for="#{label}">gender</label>
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="input-container input10">
    <input type="#{type}" id="#{label}" required="required"/>
    <label for="#{label}">date of birth</label>
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: For the date you can use the type="date" and for the gender maybe a combobox or radio buttons. The validation should be done in the JS or Backend. 
More information on the type here : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Comment: You need JS to do any conditions. Check js validations

Comment: you can use mustache ( https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify the JS library you want to use or CSS. So Using plain HTML you can do something like this:

```
 <div class="input-container input9">
  <!-- <input type="#{type}" id="#{label}" required="required"/> -->
  <select>
    <option value='male'>male</option>
    <option value='female'>female</option>
    <option value='other'>other</option>
  </select>
  <label for="#{label}">gender</label>
  <div class="bar"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="input-container input10">
    <!-- <input type="#{type}" id="#{label}" required="required"/> -->
    <input type="date" name="bday" max="1979-12-31">
    <label for="#{label}">date of birth</label>
    <div class="bar"></div>
 </div>
```

You can find out more from:
[here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_date_max_min)
and 
[here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)

Good luck